# Any way to get the app_id related to an item that has been deleted (API)

Tags: python, podio

Any way to get the app_id related to an item that has been deleted (API).

Because when I try to get details from the item_id I receive this information.

https://api.podio.com/item/xxxxxxxx

```
{u'error_parameters': {}, u'error_detail': None, u'error_propagate': False, 
u'request': {u'url': u'http://api.podio.com/item/xxxxxxxx', u'query_string': u'', u'method': u'GET'}, 
u'error_description': u'Item has been deleted', u'error': u'gone'}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your **hook URL** by adding the `app_id`, so you can figure out from which app the item got deleted.

Comment: if I add the app_id at the end of the url, like this.
/webhook?app_id=xxx
I am gonna receive this in the POST content.
item_revision_id=1&hook_id=xxx&item_id=xxx&type=item.delete&app_id=xxx

Comment: Make your hook URL like `/webhook/{app_id}` and add the wildcard in your application's routes.